# Django Admin has broken CSS link through apache, but works in runserver mode

Tags: django, django-admin, django-settings

For some reason, at some point the django administration got broken. The css is missing.

Here are my settings:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'media/'))
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/admin_media/'
```

However, the generated line on the admin page is still:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/admin_media/css/base.css" />
```

but the site gives me 404 on this file.

And it gets better - if I use apache to view the project, that problem occurs. If I use `python manage.py runserver` the admin works well.

Any clues to why that might be happening?
- restarted apache, that didn't help.

here is what i have in the urls file:

```
    (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
```

Comment: Are you serving the static media files through Django or are you serving them through Apache? If the latter, you might want to show how you set up thoses files under the Apache configuration.

Comment: if you tell me how to understand the answer, i will figure out and tell you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.

For production server, you have to setup a link to the setting you provided. For me, i chose admin_media folder, in the settings.py file:

```
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/admin_media/'
```

And in order to tell apache to look for files, you have to edit your sites-enabled file by adding the line:

```
Alias /admin_media/ /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/
```

Note though, that this is the path to the django contrib admin as installed on my server. Your server might have a different installation, so look up your settings. find out where your python is installed by copy pasting this in terminal:

```
python -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print get_python_lib()"
```

Good luck to everybody!

Comment: Thanks, this was a really useful post.  I created a symlink from the ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX to [Python]/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/ and this also worked, without having to edit the Apache virtual host file.

Comment: Well written. Fixed the exact same problem I had.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that on Django 1.4.2 the path is different. It must be pointed to /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/

Comment: The path for Django 1.4.3 in my Fedora 17 system: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/